# Double Content Editor in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am not programmer actually. But now I need a help to build Wordpress site. I want to put double content editor in Wordpress, in a custom post type. So, I can put `th_content()` (and example:) `the_content2()` in theme.

Answer (score 0):

[**Multiple content blocks**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/) plugin will help you.

```
With this plug-in, you can use more than one content "block" on a template.
You only have to insert one tag inside the template, so its easy to use.
```

**USAGE:**

Activate the plugin.

To include a double content on all your pages with default template:

Open your `page.php` file on theme folder and place `<?php the_block('block2'); ?>` after this line: `<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>`

Now goto any wordpress page and edit it. You can see the "block2" content section.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks, it's great plugin. Can it be applied only to specific custom post type?

Comment: Its made to apply for page templates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But still curious how to make double `the_content()` editor :D

Comment: Updated my answer with usage.